# Migration from Google AuthSub to OAuth2

Tags: php, zend-framework, google-oauth

I've got a few hundred users I'd like to migrate from a Zend Framework GData application using AuthSub over to OAuth2.

Is there an endpoint / way to automatically exchange their AuthSub tokens for OAuth2 tokens without them having to go through the OAuth2 approval dance?

For background, I'm using PHP 5.4 with Zend Framework's GData library to communicate with Google Spreadsheets to load data into spreadsheets for users automatically.  Many of our users completely forget who we are and just watch their data come in automatically, so avoiding having them have to log back in and give us rights they've already given once would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no seamless migration path from AuthSub to OAuth2 -- users will have to re-approve your application's access request.